# What can I do to repair my minifigures loose neck/head joint?

Tags: minifigures, repair

I have a number of loose neck joints on my minifigures. How can I repair them? Any suggestions?

Comment: Superglue. I guarantee your minifigs' heads will never fall off again. And if they do, I will pay you $-100,000.

Comment: @PeterDC putting glue on Lego is illegal in many contries!

Comment: Well, then, there's always the "stick the neck in a fire, then remove it and put the head on real fast" method.

Comment: That`s atrocious!

Comment: Discard them (I can give you my address) and buy new ones.

Comment: before it turns into a trollfest, I'll test with liquid paper and let you know if I'm about to send you my torsos by mail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the old days, minifigures had a dab of paint on the neck. I don't know if it was for this purpose but it would wear off over time.  You can paint some nail polish or acrylic on the neck to strengthen that connection. Thin the acrylic (use water based) before applying.

Comment: This is most likely a better solution than liquid paper (too thick I'd guess)

Comment: The dab of paint was most certainly for aligning purposes so that the machines which added the arms knew which side was front. But anyway, adding a small layer of paint (fluid corrector might work too) should indeed do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Don't tell anyone, but I've used brushable superglue to put a thin layer on the back of the neck.  Then I let it fully dry, and it grips the head fine.  Eventually it will wear off.  It's cheaper than nail polish and very hard to see.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend getting some clear nail varnish and coating the pin or hole with it. I did this this earlier and it really works. The minor setback is it takes 5 minutes to dry naturaly, or 2 minutes if you apply co2 (breathe on it or blow dry it until it dries to reduce the wait time to 2 minutes). I did this on a Kai, and it works well.